# I try to generate a X509Certificate2 key pair with dot-net but private key is missing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, private-key, x509certificate2

I try to create a private-public key pair with dot-net and install it in the local key store. I was confused when the private key was not installed with the public key and then I noticed that despite the certificate having the `HasPrivateKey` property set to `true` the actual `PrivateKey` property is `null`. How do I get both, private and public key to be added to the windows key store? The certificate is later needed for port binding.

My current code looks basically like this:

```
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSigned(string issuer="", string firendly_name = "")
{
using (var key = RSA.Create(4096))
{
    var req = new CertificateRequest(
        $"CN={issuer}",
        key,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    
    req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));

    req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
            new OidCollection
            {
                // Server Authentifikation
                new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"),
                // Client Authentifikation
                new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")
            },
            true));

    req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(req.PublicKey, false));


    var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(30));
    cert.FriendlyName = firendly_name;


    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(cert);
        store.Close();
    }

}
}
```

I already searched the internet but couldn't find a solution that works for me. Really scratching my head about this one for hours. The program is a installer type of program and previously called PowerShell to create a self signed certificate which only worked half of the time and was dirty as hell. I'm limited to dot-net 4.7.2 and can't rely on external libraries very much because of project constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The HasPrivateKey property set to true the actual PrivateKey property is null

You shouldn't trust or use the `PrivateKey` property, it's always null for ECDSA/ECDH/DH-based certificates, and can also be null (as you saw) for RSA and DSA.  The `GetRSAPrivateKey()` method (and others, for different algorithms) is the better answer.

> How do I get both, private and public key to be added to the windows key store?

The problem is that CertificateRequest binds the key as-is to the certificate.  You have an ephemeral key (created by `RSA.Create(4096)`) so that certificate is associated with an ephemeral key.  When you add it to the store the ephemeral key is then forgotten.

You could either change your key creation to create a named CNG key, or just export the cert as a PFX, re-import it with PersistKeySet, and add that to the store.

```
var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(30));
cert.FriendlyName = firendly_name;

using (cert)
using (var tmpCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx), "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet))
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(tmpCert);
    store.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue a while ago trying to add the certificate to the store from the code automatically for a docker container.

The solution I used was creating the self-certificate with the OpenSSL tool and save it on a folder inside the project. NOTE: I created a pfx certificate in order to have the private key inside the certificate.

So, I had a code like the following

> using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,
> StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadWrite)) {
>
> store.Add(new
> X509Certificate2("path-to-certificate/certificate-name.pfx",
> "certificatePassword"));
>
> }

NOTE2: The "StoreName.Root", and the "StoreLocation.CurrentUser" will vary depending on which store you want to save the certificate.

I hope you find this solution useful!